# Get keyerror while upgrading model in odoo 10

Tags: model, odoo, odoo-10, keyerror

When i'm upgrading customize sale module then getting below error. And after few secord server restored and upgraded. But, after every start server following error occurs during module upgradation. So, How to find error in module and what?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 640, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 677, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 333, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 101, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 326, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 935, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 506, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 889, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 877, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 689, in call_kw
    return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 680, in call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/odoo/addons/base/module/module.py", line 527, in button_immediate_upgrade
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_upgrade)
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/odoo/addons/base/module/module.py", line 484, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 82, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 335, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 237, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 136, in load_module_graph
    registry.init_models(cr, model_names, {'module': package.name})
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 313, in init_models
    model._auto_init()
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 2499, in _auto_init
    comodel = self.env[field.comodel_name]
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 760, in __getitem__
    return self.registry[model_name]._browse((), self)
  File "/opt/odoo10/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 174, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: 'rental.pack.wizard'
```

Comment: Show your code. Where is `renta.pack.wizard` defined?

Comment: Show your .py, .xml and manifest codes